# Inserting string at position x of another string

Tags: javascript

I have two variables and need to insert string `b` into string `a` at the point represented by `position`. The result I'm looking for is "I want an apple". How can I do this with JavaScript?

```
var a = 'I want apple';
var b = ' an';
var position = 6;
```

Answer (score 473, accepted):

```js
var a = "I want apple";
var b = " an";
var position = 6;
var output = [a.slice(0, position), b, a.slice(position)].join('');
console.log(output);
```

---

### Optional: As a prototype method of String

The following can be used to splice `text` within another string at a desired `index`, with an optional `removeCount` parameter.

```js
if (String.prototype.splice === undefined) {
  /**
   * Splices text within a string.
   * @param {int} offset The position to insert the text at (before)
   * @param {string} text The text to insert
   * @param {int} [removeCount=0] An optional number of characters to overwrite
   * @returns {string} A modified string containing the spliced text.
   */
  String.prototype.splice = function(offset, text, removeCount=0) {
    let calculatedOffset = offset < 0 ? this.length + offset : offset;
    return this.substring(0, calculatedOffset) +
      text + this.substring(calculatedOffset + removeCount);
  };
}

let originalText = "I want apple";

// Positive offset
console.log(originalText.splice(6, " an"));
// Negative index
console.log(originalText.splice(-5, "an "));
// Chaining
console.log(originalText.splice(6, " an").splice(2, "need", 4).splice(0, "You", 1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: For long strings, this solution is faster (because it copies less) than nickf's solution.

Comment: This solution is not faster.  I was curious about this and ran a jsperf.  This is a note to anyone who reads this in the future.  http://jsperf.com/javascript-string-splice.  Tested in latest FF/Chrome/IE10/IE9.  I would use lean nickf's approach over this one for both clarity and performance.

Comment: Well, thats very possible. The answer here is almost 3 years old, the majority of browsers and versions back then, indeed performed way faster with an *Array* join (especially IE).

Comment: I beg your pardon to have revived such an old question, but for what I'm worth it should be `var output = [a.slice(0, position + 1), b, a.slice(position)].join('');` to give the OPs "I want an apple", instead of "I wantan apple".

Comment: @PaulVon Its never wrong to correct something, so no need to pardon. Anyway, I kind of disagree. The functionally does what its intended to do, insert a string at a certain position within another string. Actually the inserted string should be like " an", which would be more correct in this instance.

Comment: With a one change you can make this solution the fastest: do not use the array conversion which is terribly slow. This makes it even 1% faster than nickf's solution. :)  https://jsperf.com/javascript-string-splice-reloaded

Comment: I added a useful polyfill to the end of this response.

Answer (score 329):

```
var output = a.substring(0, position) + b + a.substring(position);
```

**Edit: replaced `.substr` with `.substring` because `.substr` is now a legacy function** (per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Comment: According to @junkyspace https://jsperf.com/javascript-string-splice, this answer is **640x faster** than jAndy's one.

Comment: `String.prototype.substr` is deprecated now. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Comment: [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) *in this case* is a direct replacement for the deprecated  `substr`, so the answer becomes: `var output = a.substring(0, position) + b + a.substring(position);`.

Comment: It's not strictly deprecated, but legacy, so a good idea to replace as it will likely become deprecated, and is recommended by MDN to use `.substring`

Answer (score 42):

You can add this function to string class

```
String.prototype.insert_at=function(index, string)
{   
  return this.substr(0, index) + string + this.substr(index);
}
```

so that you can use it on any string object:

```
var my_string = "abcd";
my_string.insertAt(1, "XX");
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to modify native object prototype: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Comment: -1: doesn't modify original variable AND you incorrectly used `camelCase` instead of `underscore_case` in your second example

Answer (score 21):

Using **ES6 string literals**, would be much shorter:

```js
const insertAt = (str, sub, pos) => `${str.slice(0, pos)}${sub}${str.slice(pos)}`;
    
console.log(insertAt('I want apple', ' an', 6)) // logs 'I want an apple'
```

Answer (score 10):

Maybe it's even better if you determine **position** using **indexOf()** like this:

```
function insertString(a, b, at)
{
    var position = a.indexOf(at); 

    if (position !== -1)
    {
        return a.substr(0, position) + b + a.substr(position);    
    }  

    return "substring not found";
}
```

then call the function like this:

```
insertString("I want apple", "an ", "apple");
```

Note, that I put a space after the "an " in the function call, rather than in the return statement.

Comment: This is not what it was asked. Even if this was the case this wouldn't work if you have multiple occurrences of the "at" substring

Answer (score 10):

try

```
a.slice(0,position) + b + a.slice(position)
```

```js
var a = "I want apple";
var b = " an";
var position = 6;

var r= a.slice(0,position) + b + a.slice(position);

console.log(r);
```

or regexp solution

```
"I want apple".replace(/^(.{6})/,"$1 an")
```

```js
var a = "I want apple";
var b = " an";
var position = 6;

var r= a.replace(new RegExp(`^(.{${position}})`),"$1"+b);

console.log(r);
console.log("I want apple".replace(/^(.{6})/,"$1 an"));
```

Answer (score 6):

The [Underscore.String](http://epeli.github.io/underscore.string/#home) library has a function that does [Insert](http://epeli.github.io/underscore.string/#insert-string-index-substring-gt-string)

> insert(string, index, substring) => string

like so

```
insert("I want apple", 6, " an");
// => "I want an apple"
```

Comment: Not by me, but probably because there was no mention of that library in the question. But he also doesn't seem to exclude other libraries IMO..

Comment: Even though I dislike using libraries unless necessary, I upvoted to offset the downvote :P

Answer (score 6):

If ES2018's lookbehind is [available](https://caniuse.com/#search=regexp%20lookbehind), one more regexp solution, that makes use of it to "replace" at a *zero-width position* after the Nth character (similar to @Kamil Kiełczewski's, but without storing the initial characters in a capturing group):

```
"I want apple".replace(/(?<=^.{6})/, " an")
```

```js
var a = "I want apple";
var b = " an";
var position = 6;

var r= a.replace(new RegExp(`(?<=^.{${position}})`), b);

console.log(r);
console.log("I want apple".replace(/(?<=^.{6})/, " an"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = a.split(' '); 
array.splice(position, 0, b);
var output = array.join(' ');
```

This would be slower, but will take care of the addition of space before and after the an
Also, you'll have to change the value of position ( to 2, it's more intuitive now)

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix! If you don't want to manually add a space, you can do this:

```js
var a = "I want apple";
var b = "an";
var position = 6;
var output = [a.slice(0, position + 1), b, a.slice(position)].join('');
console.log(output);
```

(edit: i see that this is actually answered above, sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

Well just a small change 'cause the above solution outputs

> "I want anapple"

instead of

> "I want an apple"

To get the output as

> "I want an apple"

use the following modified code

```
var output = a.substr(0, position) + " " + b + a.substr(position);
```

Comment: yes, it's probably not desirable in *this* case, but adding an extra space automatically is almost definitely not desirable in *all* cases.

Comment: Wouldn't the correct solutions be to add the spaces in the string = ' an ', this way you can reuse the function

Answer (score 1):

**With `RegExp` replace**

```js
var a = 'I want apple';
var b = ' an';
var position = 6;
var output = a.replace(new RegExp(`^(.{${position}})(.*)`), `$1${b}$2`);

console.log(output);
```

Info:

- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Genius

BTW, you can use just one capturing group: `str.replace(/^(.{10})/, '$1replace')`
The rest of the string would remain untouched.

thanks!