# jquery append() in string position

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    abcde<img src="abc.jp" />fg
</div>

$('div').append('<img src="abc.jpg" />'); //this will append img at end of text
```

I try to add an image into div in position 6

Is any way to append image in position?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should use `<img>` tags, not `<im>`

Comment: so you want to append the img after the text 'fg'?

Comment: no between abcde & fg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

get the text of the `div` split it at the specified position and concatenate it agian. Then override the html of the div:

```
var a = $.trim($('div').text());
var b = '<img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />';
var position = 5;
var output = a.substr(0, position) + b + a.substr(position);
$('div').html(output);
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/f1aqdz0u/)

---

Notes

Using [.substr()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4364887/4202224) seems to be faster than [.splice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4364902/4202224)

I use `$.trim()` to avoid a wrong position count due to whitespace or linebreaks

The position is set to `5` because `.substr()` starts counting at `0`

Comment: @Mahi just updated my answer to add that, remove the trim and you will see

Comment: @Mahi, between `>` and `abc...` there are characters, specifically `'\n    '`, which must be accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text within paragraph tags then you can append the img after the paragraph:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>abcde</p><span>fg</span>
</div>

$('div p').append('<img src="abc.jpg" />');
```

Comment: cant put tag, because it going to post to server