# How to create an element at a specific index within the text content of an element

Tags: javascript

I'm still new to Javascript and I'm using the web for research while trying stuff out. I can however not find any reference *on how to create an element at a specific index within the text content of an element*.

I'm trying to create a highlighting function via JS, and this is what I've ended with so far

```js
let indexes = []

for (i = 0; i < document.body.innerText.length; i++) {
  if (document.body.innerText[i] == "`") {
    if(document.body.innerText[i - 1] != "\\") {
       indexes.push(i)
    }
  }
}

if (indexes.length % 2 != 0) {
  indexes.splice(indexes.length - 1)
}

console.log(indexes)
```

```html
`body`, \`body`
```

The idea is to create a wrapping `<span>` element from the range of the first index to the second, so on..., I'm baisically looking for a JS functin that would allow me to create an element at that specific index.

E.g.

```
`body` --> <span>body</span> | `Lorem ipsum, dolor` --> <span>Lorem ipsum, dolor</span>
```

It's probably just a quick hint and not someting major, but thanks anyways!

Comment: What are your criteria for which words to enclose in a `<span>`?

Comment: @pilchard. I'm sorry, what do you mean by *your criteria for which words*?

Comment: You have to create a string, do whatever you want with it and then replace the content with the new string, don't try to do it all at once in the dom

Comment: Please add a concrete sample with before / after of your expectaion

Answer (score 0):

you can insert an HTML as you would insert a regular string to the `innerHTML` property.

**You can read more about it in here:** [Inserting string at position x of another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364881/inserting-string-at-position-x-of-another-string/4364902)

Comment: So passing each of this at its according index would work just fine? `let s = ["<span class=\"code\">", "</span>"]`

Answer (score 0):

I share one simple Example to you...

create one test.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3 id="submited_name"></h3>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  placeholder="Your Name...">
        <input type="submit" id="infosubmit" name="submit" value="Submit"  onclick="submit_info()">
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submit_info(argument) {
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            document.getElementById('submited_name').innerHTML = name;
        }
    </script>
    </html>
```

for More Learn about the Javascript Refer below websites which I gives,

https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/index.htm

Comment: I'm sorry, but your example isn't the slightest what I'm looking for. I don't want to insert text into a pre-existing element.

Comment: refer this...
1. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html-dom-createelement-method
2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-dom-div-object/
3. https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_document_createelement.asp

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/delphi/create+div+javascript @simplicius

Comment: search like that, 
1. create div element in javascript
2. add html tag element in javascript
3. how to change background using javascript
4. how to change font color using javascript
etc etc....
in Google you can find all results

Comment: Haha thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for. Please read my question again and then review your answer.

Comment: for Create element at specific index, you have to use looping logic. you cannot find exact same looping logic on internet.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I'm however aware that I need to use a loop, to loop through the list of indexes.

Comment: learn about for loop, while loop, do while loop, if loop, if else loop, nested if loop etc... it is used in all languages like php, java, javascript, .net, python, android, ios... you want to understand only loop concept, & object oriented programming ...  if you want to become a Backend Developer then you have to knowlegde about that all Loops and Object Oriented Programming concepts

Comment: Haha, thanks. But loops are really nothing hard to understand.