# Insert string into string on a dynamic position

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that includes some color tags, that looks like this:

```
[GREEN][BLUE][RED]
```

The position of the tags can be different. So `[GREEN]` could be in middle or in the last position as well.

Now I have a new color tag that should be added to that list, let's call it `[YELLOW]`. So `[YELLOW]` has a dynamic position number, let's take the variable `const position = 2`. Well, that means that `[YELLOW]` should be placed in second place, which should look like this:

```
[GREEN][YELLOW][BLUE][RED]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You should array instead regex, it will be a lot easier when you have tags with special characters or in words like `That's Him`.
you can see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Can you please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364881/inserting-string-at-position-x-of-another-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const text = "[GREEN][BLUE][RED]";
const inputNumber = 2;
const addingText = "[YELLOW]";

const index = text.split("[", inputNumber).join("[").length;
const output = [text.slice(0, index), addingText, text.slice(index)].join('');

console.log(output)
```

Comment: you can update `inputNumber` dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I would have an array of placeholders like this:

```
const placeholders = ['[GREEN]', '[YELLOW]', '[BLUE]', '[RED]'];
```

When you need to add another placeholder in a certain position you simply use the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function:

```
placeholder.splice(position, 0, newPlaceholder);
```

Then when you need to use it, you just convert it to a string:

```
placeholder.join('');
```

I think this would make it much easier to handle, more readable and possibly quicker too.

Answer (score 1):

I would split this to array and then add at specific position:

```js
var text = "[GREEN][BLUE][RED]";
var matches = text.match(/\[\w+\]/g);
matches.splice(1, 0, "[YELLOW]");
var result = matches.join("")
console.log(result);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.replace` function with the following regex.

```
((?:\[.*?\]){2})
```

When you insert variable to regex using`${variable}`, you use:

```
((?:\\[.*?\\]){${position-1}})
```

```js
var listColors = "[GREEN][BLUE][RED]";
const position = 2;
var color = "[YELLOW]";


var pattern = `((?:\\[.*?\\]){${position-1}})`;
var regex = new RegExp(pattern);

var newListColors = listColors.replace(regex, `$1${color}`);
console.log(newListColors);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find in which possition the first `]` appears and then concat the `[yellow]`