# How to get minimal possible combination of 4 digit number

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion, combinations, minimum

I have 4 digit integer number. I have to get the minimal number which is a combination of those original numbers (can't start with zeros)

```
function changeDigitsOrder(num){
 return Number(num.toString().split('').sort().join(''))
}
```

It works for numbers that doesn't have 0, but how can I get 1005 from 1500

Comment: So you need to yank out the zeros and append that after the smallest non zero

Comment: Yes, it should be at least 1000

Comment: @epascarello Yes. 3070 =>  3007, 7740 => 4077

Answer (score 3):

You could switch zeros and the following value.

```js
function changeDigitsOrder(num) {
    return +num
        .toString()
        .split('')
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .join('')
        .replace(/(0+)(.)/, '$2$1');
}

console.log(changeDigitsOrder(1500)); // 1005
console.log(changeDigitsOrder(321));  //  123
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please briefly explain what  .replace(/(0+)(.)/, '$2$1'); does?

Comment: it searches for zeroes and a non zero following character and takes both groups in different order.

Answer (score 0):

I played with destructuring and [lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59636261/295783)

```js
const re = /(0{0,})+([1-9]{0,})+/g;
const smallest = num => {
  let str = num.toString().split('').sort().join('')
  let [parts] = str.matchAll(re)
  let [_, zeroes, other] = parts
  return +(other.replace(/(?<=^.{1})/, zeroes))
};

console.log(smallest(1500))
console.log(smallest(1245))
console.log(smallest(5421))
console.log(smallest(421))
```